# How to pass values to widgets inside an array in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I have this array/list in Flutter which contains some simple widgets:

```
final List<Widget> steps = [
      _step0(),
      _step1(),
      _step2(),
    ];
```

I can display all of them like this:

```
itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
   return steps[index];
}
```

But how can I pass a value to one of the widget from the `itemBuilder`?

```
Widget step0 build(String something) {}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate more, about what you want to achieve? Do you want multiple methods as your code `step1()`, `step2()` or using single method and pass argument if have.

Comment: pass some arguments if needed as commented on comment on the other answer

Comment: You should specify any issue.....

Comment: @dadumohapatra I already specified the issue: I don't know how to pass values to a widget that it has been initiated into a `List` already

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I got you, this is what you are trying to achieve you need to have a list of `Function` not `Widget`:

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List<Function> steps;

  @override
  void initState() {
    steps = [
      _step0,
      _step1,
      _step2,
    ];
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: steps.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return steps[index](somethinng: "something");
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _step0({String somethinng}) {
    return Container(child: Text(somethinng ?? "anything"));
  }

  Widget _step1({String somethinng}) {
    return Container(child: Text(somethinng ?? "anything"));
  }

  Widget _step2({String somethinng}) {
    return Container(child: Text(somethinng ?? "anything"));
  }
}
```

If you can adjust your scenario to match with one method(without `step0`, `step1`, ...), you can try something like below or get an idea and do some changes to your scenario:

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: ListView(
          children: List.generate(10, (int index) {
            return ParentWidget(
              data: index,
              function: () => print("whooo! $index"),
              child: Text(index.toString(), style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)),
            );
          }),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ParentWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final Widget child;
  final int data;
  final Function function;

  ParentWidget({this.child, this.data, this.function});

  @override
  _ParentWidgetState createState() => _ParentWidgetState();
}

class _ParentWidgetState extends State<ParentWidget> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    print(widget.data);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: widget.function,
      child: Container(
        child: (widget.child != null) ? widget.child : SizedBox(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

If you have large collection of data, please dont use, `List.generate()` use `ListView.builder` like you are doing right now.

If this not what you are looking for please let me know to delete this answer.

Comment: That's perfect! Thanks mate

Comment: Unfortunately this just works for `Stateles` widgets. When you try to change the state on one of those widgets it doesn't work

Comment: @Dani That was not in your question right? so, according to what you have I provided an answer, if I correct.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it just changing to List of Functions returning Widgets. In your case you would need to:

```
final List<Function> steps = [
  (input) => _step0(input),
  (input) => _step1(input),
  (input) => _step2(input),
];
```

Then when you loop over it you just pass the argument to the constructor as:

```
itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
   return steps[index](input);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this?:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return _myListView(context);
  }
}

Widget _myListView(BuildContext context) {
  final List<Widget> steps = [
    _step0(1),
    _step1(2),
    _step2(3),
  ];

  return ListView.builder(
    itemCount: steps.length,
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
      return steps[index];
    },
  );
}

_step0(int number) {
  print(number);
}

_step1(int number) {
  print(number);
}

_step2(int number) {
  print(number);
}
```

Comment: but you have already the value you're passing on the `List`. Let's say that you need to do some calculation inside your `itemBuilder` and pass some dynamic value, how would you send that?

Comment: In this case maybe I would use a Provider, or a variable with a stateful widget, and update accordingly. Lets say with a (if index == 2 -> variable == whatever logic you want).

Comment: Got you. I have a provider already but that information inside it is being shared through my pages. In this case, I don't want this information outside this widget. Is there no other possible way then?

Comment: I dont see the problem in share the Provider. But you could use some logic to send diffent info withouth need of any Provider. To help with implementation would need more of your code and know more, and why.

Comment: I mean, there is no problem using the provider but imo I think it should be used just to share info, right?

Comment: What else do you need? It's basically that

Comment: Dear @dani please elaborate the need of such a thing you are asking. Then we can get an idea.

Comment: But you could have some logic that return different data depending of index. Hope somebody else share another way ;-)

Comment: the only solution I thought was creating a separate `List` with the values I'd need to share and pick them by index inside their widgets but doesn't seem too clean to me. But if that avoid the using of a provider I'd prefer it